# Entity Framework Code First - Eager Loading not working as expected?

Tags: linq-to-entities, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, code-first

I have the following Entity Framework POCO classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;} 
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public int OrderTypeId {get;set;}

    public virtual OrderType Type {get;set;}
    public virtual Customer Customer {get;set;}
} 

public class OrderType 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders {get;set;}
}
```

The problem is that when I return my `ICollection<Order>` I'm getting the `Order`s alright, but the `OrderType` property of the `Order` is not being populated. My Order will contain the following detail:

```
Id:          1
CustomerId:  1
Customer:    Populated
OrderTypeId: 3
Type:        null        // Never returned
```

My mapping code looks like the following:

```
public void ConfigureOrder(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    // Mapping from Order -> Customer
    builder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.Customer)
            .WithMany(x => x.Orders)
                .HasConstraint((order, cust) => order.CustomerId == cust.Id);

    // Mapping from Order -> OrderType
    builder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.OrderType)
            .WithMany(x => x.Orders)
                .HasConstraint((order, type) => order.OrderTypeId == type.Id);
}
```

I've then disabled Lazy loading in my context:

```
public Context(string connectionString)
    : base(connectionString)
{
    ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

So to return the data in my repository I use the `Include` method of `System.Data.Entity`:

```
var query = from item in context.Customers
                .Include(x=> x.Orders)
            where item.Id == customerId
            select item;
```

I was assuming that because I couldn't specify `Orders.OrderType`, that was the problem, so I tried some variations:

```
1 -> .Include(x=> x.Orders.FirstOrDefault().OrderType)
2 -> .Include("Orders")
3 -> .Include("Orders")
     .Include("Orders.OrderType")
```

But I can never get the OrderType property to be returned, unless I just load the Order directly:

```
var query = from item in context.Orders
                .Include(x=> x.OrderType)
            select item;
```

This code will correctly return the OrderType within the order.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Oh dear. Looks like I was a total donkey. It's 17:45, I should of gone home by now anyway.

I had two Get methods:

```
Get(int customerId)
{
    // This was the method I was testing within
    var query = from item in context.Customers
                    .Include("Orders.OrderType")
                select item;
}

Get(int customerId, int versionId)
{
    // This was the method that was running
    var query = from item in context.Customers
                    .Include(item.Orders)
                select item;
}
```

So, `"Orders.OrderType"` was the correct, albeit nasty looking solution. I need some caffeine.

**EDIT:**

Just coming back to this question, the best way for includes is to use `System.Data.Entity`'s Include method:

```
.Include(x=> x.Orders.Select(o=> o.OrderType));
```