# Entity Framework - Navigating and Including properties through collections

Tags: linq-to-entities, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, code-first

I've just had a massive [*blonde moment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780480/entity-framework-code-first-eager-loading-not-working-as-expected), but it's highlighted an annoyance I have with Entity Framework. I have disabled lazy loading so I'm forcing myself to actually think about what data I require in order to keep the application as fast as possible.

So in order to return data within a query, I need to make use of the `Include` method:

```
var query = from item in context.Customers
                .Include(x=> x.Orders)
            select item
```

This is fine until I want to select an item a bit deeper into the hierarchy. I.e:

```
Customer 1-* Orders *-1 Factory 1-1 Factory Type
```

As far as I know, the only way to return all this data ***eagerly*** would be to do the following:

```
var query = from item in context.Customers
                .Include("Orders.Factory.FactoryType")
            select item
```

With the above I'm unable to make use of the `System.Data.Entity` Lambdas as per my first example. Does anyone know if I'm missing something obvious here, or am I stuck with using string declarations for my navigation properties through collections?

If I didn't have any collections, I could just write:

```
.Include(x=> x.Order.OrderType.Factory.FactoryType) // No bother
```

But because of the `Orders` collection, there's no way to step through to a child property as far as I can tell (`FirstOrDefault`, `SingleOrDefault`, etc, do not work).

---

**it's just a turn-of-phrase, I happen to be very fond of blondes*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For including EntityCollections you use the ***Select*** method:

```
var query = from item in context.Customers
           .Include(c => c.Orders.Select(o => o.Factory.FactoryType))
           select item
```

Please note that this is not an overload of the standard [***ObjectQuery<T>.Include Method***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) and is merely an extension method on *[**ObjectQuery<T>**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345303.aspx)* Class coming with **[*EF CTP4*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4announcement.aspx)**.