# ASP.NET Web Api Error The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created 2 tables. Test table with ( ID, name, group_id ) fields and group_master with ( group_id, group_name ).

The group_id from Test table relationship with the group_master group_id.

If i have not set a relationship key, the web api is working fine and returning me the list as xml.

If there is an reference to another table, the web api is throwing an error.

**"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'"**

This happens only fields with relationship.

What could be the issue and important this "**I am new to .net**".

Thanks!

Comment: Please include your code in the question!

Comment: Chances are you have created a cycle in your object graph.  The default serializer can't handle that scenario.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641386/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api