# Exception Fetching db data in WEBAPI controller in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return some data to client page using webAPI. Please see below the exception am currently seeing while trying to access the api/controller from a browser

StackTrace
`System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeAndVerifyType(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean verifyKnownType, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiTypeAtTopLevel(DataContract dataContract, XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle originalDeclaredTypeHandle, Type graphType) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObjectContent(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalWriteObject(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObjectHandleExceptions(XmlWriterDelegator writer, Object graph, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject(XmlWriter writer, Object graph) at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.<>c__DisplayClass7.<WriteToStreamAsync>b__6() at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously(Action action, CancellationToken token)`

Controller GET method that returns the Quotes is

```
    // GET api/<controller>
    private ForumDBDataContext db = new ForumDBDataContext(); 

    public dynamic GetQuotes()
    {
        var ret = (from qt in db.vwUsersQuotess.ToList()                      
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = qt.Desc,
                       Price= qt.price,
                       Qty = qt.Quantity
                   }).AsEnumerable();
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `ToList()` instead of `AsEnumerable()`:

```
public dynamic GetQuotes()
    {
        var ret = (from qt in db.vwUsersQuotess                      
                   select new
                   {
                       Message = qt.Desc,
                       Price= qt.price,
                       Qty = qt.Quantity
                   }).ToList();
        return ret;
    }
```

If you use EntityFramework and SQL Server you can also remove the call to `vwUsersQuotess.ToList()` and do the projection (select new...) directly on the SQL server, so that the query that is being executed only retrieves the necessary columns (Desc, price and Quantity).

Comment: tried that and got this

An error has occurred.The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.System.InvalidOperationExceptionAn error has occurred.Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[<>f__AnonymousType1`7[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],

Comment: Please checkout these answers for the possible cause of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641386/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api

Comment: Thanks Lucien, followed the link and tried the following and it worked just fine:

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Remove(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);