# 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

the old question solved to json side 
I get normal response from API when I request content type 'text/json
and the problem when 
 I request content type 'text/xml;
I get this message 
    An error has occurred.The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace /><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>There was an error generating the XML document.</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType><StackTrace>   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.&lt;WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync&gt;d__1b.MoveNext()</StackTrace><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>The type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[testtransotels.data.cities, testtransotels, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] may not be used in this context.System.InvalidOperationException   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterObject.Write1_Object(String n, String ns, Object o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterObject.Write2_anyType(Object o)

my code as you see

```
   private datacontext db = new datacontext();
 public object Post([FromBody]Request Request)
    {
        return db.Student;

    }
 public class Student
{
    [DataMember]

    public string StudentID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]

    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]

    public string StudentCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641386/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api

Comment: This was answered previously. Check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641386/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api

Comment: the answer for json and didn't help me for xml